# Proving the Riemann Integrability of the Maximum of Two Integrable Functions on a Closed Interval.Proof check.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $P_1$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $U(P_1,f) - L(P_1,f) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and let $P_2$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $U(P_2,g) - L(P_2,g) < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now define a partition $P$ which is the union of the dividing points of $P_1$ and $P_2$.

For $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$, we have

$$
U(P,h) - L(P,h) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^h - m_i^h)(x_i - x_{i-1}),
$$

where

$$
(M_i^h - m_i^h) = \begin{cases} M_i^f - m_i^f, & \text{if } f(x) = \max\{f(x), g(x)\}, \\ M_i^g - m_i^g, & \text{if } g(x) = \max\{f(x), g(x)\}, \end{cases}
$$

and $M_i$, $m_i$ are the supremum and infimum of the functions in the intervals of $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n+1$.

The sum

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^h - m_i^h)(x_i - x_{i-1})
$$

can be split as follows:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&= \sum \text{for intervals where } f(x) = \max\{f(x), g(x)\}(M_i^f - m_i^f)(x_{k-1} - x_k) \\ &\quad + \sum \text{for intervals where } g(x) = \max\{f(x), g(x)\}(M_i^g - m_i^g)(x_{j-1} - x_j), 
\end{aligned}
$$

which leads to:

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum (M_i^f - m_i^f)(x_{k-1} - x_k) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^f - m_i^f)(x_i - x_{i-1}), \\ \sum (M_i^g - m_i^g)(x_{j-1} - x_j) &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^g - m_i^g)(x_i - x_{i-1}).
\end{align*}
$$

Finally, we obtain:

$$
\begin{aligned}
U(P,h) - L(P,h) &= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^h - m_i^h)(x_i - x_{i-1}) \\ &= \sum (M_i^f - m_i^f)(x_{k-1} - x_k) \\ &\quad + \sum (M_i^g - m_i^g)(x_{j-1} - x_j) \\ &\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^f - m_i^f)(x_i - x_{i-1}) \\ &\quad + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} (M_i^g - m_i^g)(x_i - x_{i-1}) \\ &< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, $h(x)=\max\{f(x),g(x)\}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: It's hard to read. A simpler approach: observe that $$\max(f,g)={1\over 2}[|f+g|+|f-g|]$$ and use the fact that the sum, difference and composition with continuous function ($y\mapsto |y|$ ) of Riemann integrable functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: I edited it, and I think, it is more readable now, but I am splitting the difference between the upper and lower Darboux sums, into the intervals in which f(x) is the maximum and those where g(x) is the maximum and I am then saying that each of these two sums is smaller than the difference between the two Darboux sums over the whole interval, which was chosen such that it's smaller than eps/2.

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: This tag should be used when you have a proposed solution to a problem and have *specific concerns* or doubts about the validity of that solution. A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough

Comment: Well, I have provided a solution and I have concerns, which tag should I use then?

Comment: I think your solution is not correct. In  one interval of the partition we may have both behaviours $f(x)\ge g(x)$ and $f(x')\le g(x').$ It may occur that $M_i^h=M_i^g-m_i^f.$

Comment: You are right, I missed that, but can't I take the intervals so small that I have only f(x)>=g(x) or f(x)<=g(x). I will choose the partition P such that it combines all of the points in P1 and P2 and the intervals are chosen such that either f(x) is the maximum or g(x) is the maximum.

Comment: It is impossible even if both functions are continuous. Consider $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ and $g(x)=0$ on $[0,1].$

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now that it's wrong, I graphed both functions on [0,1], but I still don't understand exactly why I can't find such a partition that only one of the functions is the maximum, since I can take whatever partition I want, and thus make the intervals as small as I would like. Is it because they still need to have a length greater than zero or something like that? Sorry for asking stupid questions.